# Jboss 7 and datasources

Tags: oracle11g, jboss7.x

I successfully configured Jboss 7 to work with Oracle 11g by installing the jdbc drivers as a module and adding the datasource definition in the standalone.xml.
However, now I want to move the datasource definition to it's own file which I dropped into the deployments directory.
That resulted in the following failure:

```
 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/MyDatasource -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.jdbc.MyDatasource
```

Is that not possible anymore with jboss 7?(I believe it used to be the case with jboss 5)  Here is how the ds file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema">  
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/MyDatasource" pool-name="OracleDS" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.host:1521:mydb</connection-url>
    <driver>
        oracle
    </driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>                  
        <prefill>false</prefill>
        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>user</user-name>
        <password>pass</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
        <use-fast-fail>false</use-fast-fail>
    </validation>
</datasource>
    <drivers>
     <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.jdbc"/>
    </drivers>  
</datasources>
```

Comment: It turns out 7.0 doesn't support separate ds files. But 7.1 does.
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/375-jboss-as-7-deployable-datasources.html

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you are doing the jndi look up,but from the error message it looks you are using the normal (old way) of `java:jdbc/DatasourceName` instead of the new [way](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-DatasourceDefinitions%5d) `java:jboss/datasources/DatasourceName.`

Answer (score 0):

I tried xxx-ds.xml for data source configuration.

I got a WARN

```
12:22:12,988 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployer.dsdeployer] 
(MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010411: <drivers/> in standalone -ds.xml 
deployments aren't supported: Ignoring xxx-ds.xml
```

So from the message, I confirmed that JBoss7 doesn't support a separate ds file in stadalone mode.

Comment: I do not know what version you are using, but from the jboss-as-7 mailing list I ready that deploying -ds.xml files is not supported. they probably have a slightly different xsd than before though.

Comment: My understanding is you can deploy datasource files, you just can't define drivers.  You can, however, reference the class file of an already deployed JDBC driver.